# command line input in java

Tags: command-line, java

Trying to provide input via command in a java program.Here is the code.

```
public class Hola {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

But when try to run it via command line it showes error.I am using ubuntu 18.04. Here is the error:

> Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Hola
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Hola has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are building and running your program, as well as the outputs of `java --version` and `javac --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you compiled your Java program with a version of the compiler that is more recent than the version of the Java virtual machine you're trying to execute the compiled code.

In your case 58 means Java 14 and 55 means Java 11. Thus, you compiled your program with Java 14 and you're trying to execute the compiled code with Java 11.

Probably your configuration of the Java virtual machine is not in sync with your configuration of your Java compiler.

Maybe you ran something like `sudo update-alternatives --config java` (JVM) but not `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` (Java compiler).

To avoid such problems, in Ubuntu, you can run `sudo update-java-alternatives`, which takes care of setting the version both for `java` and for `javac`.